# PHP move_uploaded_file error - failed to open stream

Tags: php, image, upload

```
<?php
if($_FILES['img']['error']>0){
echo "Error: No file selected!";
}
else {
echo "File name ".$_FILES['img']['name']."<br>";
echo "File size ".round($_FILES['img']['size'] / 1024,1)." kb <br>";
echo "File type ".$_FILES['img']['type']."<br>";
echo "File tmp ".$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']."<br>";
$extension = end(explode(".",$_FILES['img']['name']));
echo "file format: ".$extension."<br>";
$name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['img']['size'];
if(file_exists("uploads/".$name)){
echo $_FILES['img']['name']." exists";
}
if($extension != "jpg" && $extension != "png" && $extension != "gif"){
echo "File with format: ".$extension." is not aviable to upload";
}
if($size > 1000000) {
echo $size." is greater than 1 mb !";
}
elseif(empty($name)) {
echo "No file selected!";
}
elseif($extension != "jpg" && $extension != "png" && $extension != "gif" && $_FILES['img']['size'] > 1000000 && file_exists("uploads/".$name)){
echo $name." exists";
echo "File with format: ".$extension." is not aviable to upload";
echo $size." is greater than 1 mb !";
}

else {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"uploads/".$name);
echo "The file was succesfully uploaded";
}
}
?>
```

Hey, I'm trying to upload an files... but its showing error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/51.jpg)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in Z:\home\test1.ru\www\views\admin\save.php on line 35
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move 'Z:\tmp\phpB178.tmp' to 'uploads/51.jpg' in
>   Z:\home\test1.ru\www\views\admin\save.php on line 35

And ofc it dont upload the file.. Whats wrong with this?

Comment: "No such file or directory" thats not clear?

Comment: Set right permissions to uploads folder...

Comment: It means it can create the file (maybe already exists?), or cannot access the directory that you are trying to access. See @nevermind 's comment

Comment: save.php is in /admin/save.php - uploads folder is in /admin/uploads/ - Any solution? About permissions, what permissions (on windows)

Comment: How should i write the correct path then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

There should be views/admin/uploads/